How to repeat a function with generated results in R?
I need to know the size of a population after 4 years given an initial population size, growth rate, and death rate. I was given that the population starts at 100 individuals (N0 = 100), grows at a rate of 1, and dies at a rate of 0.5. In the function below, lambda is equal to 1 + growth - death. I can find the population size after 4 years with the following function, but how would I expand this to say, 100 years? Is there a way to make N# automatically be filled by the population size in the previous year? I have been searching how to do this but can't quite figure it out.
Scenario1 <-    function(N0,lambda){
  N1 <- N0 * lambda     
  N2 <- N1 * lambda     
  N3 <- N2 * lambda     
  N4 <- N3 * lambda     
  return(N4)   
} 

lambda = 1 + 1 - 0.5

N_Scenario1 <- Scenario1(100, lambda)

I tried wrapping the function in a for loop but I could not figure out exactly how to input new values into the function.

Does "grows at a rate of 1 mean one individual or a 100% ratio?"?

for a grouth of g, a death rate of 0.5, do you mean function(N0, d, g, num_years) {N0 * ((1 + g - d) ^ num_years)}?

This calculates and creates a semilog plot of the population as it evolves over time: N0 <- 100; lambda = 1 + 1 - 0.5; maxyear <- 4; year <- 0:maxyear; pop <- data.frame(year, N = N0 * lambda ^ year); pop; plot(pop, type = "h", log = "y")

Instead of using loops, you can create a function for any number of years given a growth rate (g), death rate (d), and initial population size (n0):
scenario1 <- function(n0, g = 1, d = 0.5, years = 4) {
  n0 * (1 + g - d) ^ years
}

# test that function returns same as OP's known function
all.equal(scenario1(100), Scenario1(100, lambda))
# [1] TRUE

# 10 years
scenario1(100, years = 10)
# [1] 5766.504


You can use a for loop to update the input of the function each time by using the output variable as both the argument and the result of the function.
Scenario1 <- function(n, lambda) {
  return(n * lambda)
}

lambda = 1 + 1 - 0.5

input <- 100

output <- input
for(i in 1:4) {
  output <- Scenario1(output, lambda)
}


Now the function Scenario1 is just the same as multiplication, i.e. the function *, which already exists in base R. The loop is just a slow way of multiplying input by lambda raised to the fourth power. You could just write output <- input * lambda^4 instead of defining a pointless function and writing a loop. Or am I mistaken?

I'm not sure what the output you're looking for is. I wrote my answer to match yours but without repeating the multiplication in the function. Maybe you would want to change the function to return(n + (n * growth) - (n * decay)) ?
